# SQL UNION VIEW, i have conflicting ID numbers and need to create generic field ID,

Tags: sql, union-all

My thinking was to create 001 + PLSupplierAccountID for RWL

and 002 + PLSupplierAccountID for FAH and so on.....

how do i go about doing this?

```
SELECT    PLSupplierAccountID AS AccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'RWL' AS Company
FROM         Roth.dbo.PLSupplierAccount
UNION ALL
SELECT     PLSupplierAccountID AS AccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'FAH' AS Company
FROM         FAH.dbo.PLSupplierAccount
UNION ALL
SELECT     PLSupplierAccountID AS AccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'RFG' AS Company
FROM         RFG.dbo.PLSupplierAccount
UNION ALL
SELECT     PLSupplierAccountID AS AccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'RFP' AS Company
FROM         RFP.dbo.PLSupplierAccount
UNION ALL
SELECT    PLSupplierAccountID AS AccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'RFW' AS Company
FROM         ALOPS.dbo.PLSupplierAccount
```

Comment: What database are you using?  And, can you provide examples of what you want as output?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question correctly then since you can't have a numeric field starting with zero, simply convert the `PLSupplierAccountID` to a `VARCHAR` and pre-pend with `00x` like so:

```
SELECT    '001' + CAST(PLSupplierAccountID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS AccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'RWL' AS Company
FROM         Roth.dbo.PLSupplierAccount
UNION ALL
SELECT     '002' + CAST(PLSupplierAccountID AS VARCHAR(10))AS AccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'FAH' AS Company
FROM         FAH.dbo.PLSupplierAccount
UNION ALL
SELECT     '003' + CAST(PLSupplierAccountID AS VARCHAR(10))AS AccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'RFG' AS Company
FROM         RFG.dbo.PLSupplierAccount
UNION ALL
SELECT     '004' + CAST(PLSupplierAccountID AS VARCHAR(10))AS AccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'RFP' AS Company
FROM         RFP.dbo.PLSupplierAccount
UNION ALL
SELECT    '005' + CAST(PLSupplierAccountID AS VARCHAR(10))AS AccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'RFW' AS Company
FROM         ALOPS.dbo.PLSupplierAccount
```

Comment: That works perfect thank you, is there a way of keeping it as numeric?

Comment: Not if you want `00` at the front because that makes no sense for a numeric type. But you could convert to a string, prepend an arbitrary number like `111`, `222` etc and then convert back to a number (make sure it's big enough - '111' on the front of '123456789' converted to `INT` would result in an overflow, it would need to be `BIGINT`)

Comment: Of course that means once you get to 999 you need to be a bit clever, but I'll leave that to your imagination :)

Comment: Thanks Steve, I have tried the following code but i think they are being added together not combined? im obviously doing something wrong

Comment: SELECT     '111' + CAST(PLSupplierAccountID AS BIGINT) AS IDnumber, PLSupplierAccountID AS AccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, 
                      SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'RWL' AS Company
FROM         Roth.dbo.PLSupplierAccount

Comment: No, you need two conversions like so: `SELECT CAST('111' + CAST(666 AS VARCHAR(10)) AS BIGINT)`. Obviously this won't be terribly good from a performance point of view if you have lots of records and tables.